# ViewModel "no key defined" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I've recently been learning asp.net MVC 5 and EF6 and i've started to develop viewmodels for my views instead of stuffing values into the viewbag.

I this is my viewmodel called **EmployeeCreate**

```
namespace Rota.ViewModels
{
    public class EmployeeCreate
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

what i would like to do is on the create `[httpget] action method` to be able to populate a dropdown list

this is my **Employee** enitity

```
namespace Rota.Models
{
    public class Employee 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Department")]
        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="No Department")]
        public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and this is my **Department** entity

```
    namespace Rota.Models
    {
        public class Department
        {
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
            public int ID { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Edit** this is my **DbContext** class

```
public class RotaContext : DbContext
    {
        public RotaContext() : base("RotaContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Schedule> Scheduled { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Rota.ViewModels.EmployeeCreate> CreateEmployeeViewModels { get; set; }

    }
```

this is my **Create Action** method in my controller

```
namespace Rota.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        //establish database connection
        private RotaContext db = new RotaContext();

        //GET: Employee/Create
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            EmployeeCreate ViewModel = new EmployeeCreate()
            {
                Departments = db.Departments.Select(department => new SelectListItem {
                    Value = department.ID.ToString(),
                    Text = department.Name
                })
            };
            return View(ViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble i've got is that i keep getting this error :

> **One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:**
>
> Rota.Entities.EmployeeCreate: : EntityType 'EmployeeCreate' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType. CreateEmployeeViewModels:
>   EntityType: EntitySet 'CreateEmployeeViewModels' is based on type
>   'EmployeeCreate' that has no keys defined.

I have no idea why the application thinks my viewmodel is an entity, i can't see anything here that might suggest as such, to my knowledge, i thought i was populating an object with values from a database, and becuase the viewmodel has absolutely no association with the entities other than this, it doesn't need a key, because it doesn't need a unique identifier.

**Full Stack Trace**

> [ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected
>   during model generation:
>
> Rota.Entities.EmployeeCreate: : EntityType 'EmployeeCreate' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType. CreateEmployeeViewModels:
>   EntityType: EntitySet 'CreateEmployeeViewModels' is based on type
>   'EmployeeCreate' that has no keys defined. ]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate() +338
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +370
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) +288
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) +94
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +248
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +543    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +26
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +21    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +64    System.Linq.Queryable.Select(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector) +85    Rota.Controllers.EmployeeController.Create() in
>   d:\Development\Rota\Rota\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs:87
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +139
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>   +112    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>   +452    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +37    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +241
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +19
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: can you show the full stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Rota.ViewModels.EmployeeCreate>   CreateEmployeeViewModels { get; set; }
```

This is not required in your context class. If you have this, EF tries to create DB object for your viewmodel. For every "DbSet" you give in context class, EF creates DB object. Try removing this.

Comment: In MVC 5, remove Data Context Class from 'Data Context Class' field on create view dialog.